# Is it possible to create new property in QueryBuilder?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

With chats-room entity storing a conversation, I design like this

**`chat-room.entity.ts`**

```
@Entity('chats-room')
export class Chatroom {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    chatroomId:string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User,user => user.chatrooms)
    userOne:User

    @ManyToOne(() => User,user => user.chatrooms)
    userTwo:User

    @OneToMany(() => ChatRoomMessage,message => message.chatroom)
    chatRoomMessages:ChatRoomMessage[]
}
```

**`chat-room-message.entity.ts`**

```
@Entity('chats-room-message')
export class ChatRoomMessage {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  messageId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.chatRoomMessages)
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Chatroom, (chatroom) => chatroom.chatRoomMessages)
  chatroom: Chatroom;

  @Column()
  content?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp with time zone' })
  timestamp: Date;
}
```

And this query to get all **chats-room entity**

```
const chatRoomRepository = this.dataSource.getRepository(Chatroom);
      const chatRooms = await chatRoomRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('chats-room')
        .select('chats-room')
        .where('chats-room.userOne.userId=:id', {
          id: user.userId,
        })
        .orWhere('chats-room.userTwo.userId=:id', {
          id: user.userId,
        })
        .leftJoinAndSelect('chats-room.userOne', 'userOne')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('chats-room.userTwo', 'userTwo')
        .getMany();
```

But there is my problem, I want to create last Message property in every chats-room item. My solution is map chatroom array and add new property in item :

```
const chatRoomMessageRepository = this.dataSource.getRepository(ChatRoomMessage);
Promise.all(
        chatRoom.map(
          async (item: any) =>
            (item.lastMessage = await chatRoomMessageRepository.findOne({
              where: {
                chatroom: item,
              },
              order: {
                timestamp: 'DESC',
              },
              relations: {
                chatroom: true,
              },
            })),
        ),
      ).then((data) => console.log(data));
```

I think it is so many query,Are there some solution better?